# Careers does not give me any response

Tags: support, jobs

I have around 6600+ Stack Overflow reputation points, and I have my profile on Stack Overflow Careers!

I have been available there for the past one year, but I have never got any relevant offer from anyone at Careers!

Can anyone tell what to do to get noticed on Careers, or will I never get any help from it?

If this question is not suited here then let me know, and I will delete it and also provide a replacement!

Please tell me what to do, because currently I am looking for change!

Comment: Have you applied for any positions or are you passively waiting/expecting a job offer to land in your inbox?

Comment: i have already applied but never got any response!

Comment: When did you apply?

Comment: i have applied for different posts and i use to apply when i get something similar to my expectation!

Comment: I would suggest you to be patient and to persevere with your applications.

Comment: but i have applied so many times and that also for more than one year!! thts quite long time

Answer (score 12):

First, stop shouting! :)

I took a look at your profile, and it looks .. *okay*. It shows someone that is probably competent with C#, but it doesn't say much else. Let's start at the top, you're working on .. sockets. Okay, that's neat .. *what* are you doing with them? What cool things have you accomplished? What was your previous project?

With only two years in the field, I don't think anyone would expect you to have a *lot* of accomplishments listed. In light of that, why not talk about the stuff you really *wish* you could get paid to work on? It's easy to say you're passionate, but your profile is so terse that it doesn't really convey that.

There's also not a lot of code that can be found for you - have you worked on any personal projects and made them available on something like Github? This shows evidence that you just love programming, you do it even when you're *not* paid, and that you're comfortable showing your code to the world. No hiring manager is going to be able to tell how well you comprehend MVC unless you have something to show where you did.

There's just not a lot there to go on, nothing that really makes you stand out for someone that's going through a bunch of possible profiles. Build it out with more public artifacts of your love for coding, ask a friend to help proofread it and be patient.

It's not bad, it just looks .. unfinished.

Comment: I am not shouting Tim! I just love SO so much that i pass so much time here thats why i wanted to know what is wrong! thanks alot for taking time and do the analysis!  I need to work alot to get noticed! It is sad to get above comments but it is also motivating me to do much more things! Thanks alot Sir!

Comment: @Neel It's not sad. It's a happy thing. You've done enough to demonstrate competence, which is _a lot_ more than many others competing for jobs in your field have done. All you need now is some shine and polish. Just get some passion and fun in that profile, I'm _certain_ you'll do well if you do.

Comment: Your above comment is enough to fill me with more motivation! Yes, I will surely give my best and one day will work in my dream company which is Stack Exchange! :) again thanks a lot for the precious words Tim! You are awesome!

Comment: and i have even update my profile :- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/neelbhatt